# How do I inject a repository into a custom MembershipProvider using AutoFac

Tags: c#, asp.net, autofac

I created a custom membership provider

```
public class MyMembership : MembershipProvider
{
    private IRepository<User> Repo;
}
```

I figured out how to inject MyMembership using autofac:

```
builder.Register(c => Membership.Provider);
```

However, this doesn't work if I have a constructor that takes an IRepository (it only calls the parameterless constructor.)  I tried doing changing from a private field to a public property and calling:

```
builder.Register(c => Membership.Provider).AutoWireProperties();
```

The problem is, MembershipProvider doesn't have a Repo property, it's only my class.

For the time being, I've not injected anything, and just created an empty constructor where I simply create a new instance of my Repo.  But it makes it harder for testing.

So, is there any way that I can use AutoFac to inject my MyMembership, and have it use the injected Repo?

Comment: How do you subclass from Membership? The class is static.

Comment: My bad, it's MembershipProvider, not Membership that I was deriving from.  Good catch @Jehof

Comment: I have a custom membership provider class which I want Autofac to resolve it as Membership.Provider, how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It's not possible.

The `DependencyResolver` is not used for the providers (roles/membership) etc.

I've made a membership provider which uses `DependencyResolver` internally. All you need to do is to implement `IAccountRepository` and register it in your container.

http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/09/a-more-structured-membershipprovider/

Answer (score 2):

It's an old post, so i'll just post here my solution as I struggle with it a bit myself.

**public class AutofacBootstrapperImp : AutofacBootstrapper**

In your autofac builder setup include register for your interface

```
builder.RegisterType<YourRepo>().As<IRepository<User>>().SingleInstance();
```

**public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider**

Overload init method and use autofac scope to resolve your type

```
private IRepository<User> Repo;

    public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config)
    {
        // use autoface scope to resole service
        using (var scope = AutofacBootstrapper.Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            Repo = scope.Resolve<IRepository<User>>();
        }

        if (config == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("config");

        // Initialize the abstract base class.
        base.Initialize(name, config);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also register the `IRepository<User>`. But to do that you need to access your custom provider by its concrete type.

So something like this:

```
builder.Register( c => Membership.Provider );
builder.Register( c => ((MyMembership) Membership.Provider).Repo );
```

That could be made nicer (avoiding casts by registering your implementation) as follows, but not sure on how it then fits in with ASP.NET and its management of provider lifecycles:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyMembership>();
builder.Register( c => c.Resolve<MyMembership>() ).As<MembershipProvider>();
builder.Register( c => c.Resolve<MyMembership>().Repo );
```

EDIT:

but from a design standpoint, it looks like your `MyMembership` class has a dependency on the `IRepository<User>`, therefor something like this is probably best:

```
builder.RegisterType<YourRepositoryImplementation>().As<IRepository<User>>();
builder.RegisterType<MyMembership>();
builder.Register( c => c.Resolve<MyMembership>() ).As<MembershipProvider>();
```

That way the IRepository will be injected into the MyMembership as needed, but also be available for direct consumption by other components, and they all have the lifetime management handled by Autofac.

Comment: Awesome.  I have already registered IRepository<User> elsewhere.  When I get home tonight I'll try these out, thanks.

Comment: Just did some reading up on custom MembershipProviders and it seems ASP.NET instantiates the instance for you, so the last 2 options above will not work, well not correctly at least. You will have an instance constructed by ASP.NET (returned by `Membership.Provider`) and the instance constructed by Autofac.

Your best bet is probably the first option.

Comment: Ack, but then I see your problem, you want the custom provider constructed by ASP.NET to be injected with the `IRepository<User>` instance already registered. Unless ASP.NET provide some hooks for membership provider instantiation, your probably gonna have to use the Service Locator anti-pattern within your `MyMembership` constructor to resolve the `IRepository<User>`.

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is entirely possible. In my `Bootstrapper.cs` class, I just inject the properties into the providers as such:

```
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

        var lifetimeScope = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ILifetimeScope>();
        lifetimeScope.InjectProperties(Membership.Provider);
        lifetimeScope.InjectProperties(Roles.Provider);
```

I also have the following:

```
        builder.Register(context => Membership.Provider).ExternallyOwned();
        builder.Register(context => Roles.Provider).ExternallyOwned();
```

however I'm not entirely sure if it's even necessary. I believe the `Register`s are there in case you want to inject the provider into a type.